# Get data from jobs table / json, Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to extract some specific data from this JSON, like the ID of the FacetofaceSession session (114) from `data->command`, there is a simple way of doing that?

```
{
  "uuid": "0c1c038e-72c5-4cec-98d1-620ff4b0df20",
  "displayName": "App\\Listeners\\SendConfirmationNotification",
  "job": "Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
  "maxTries": null,
  "maxExceptions": null,
  "delay": null,
  "timeout": null,
  "timeoutAt": null,
  "data": {
    "commandName": "Illuminate\\Events\\CallQueuedListener",
    "command": "O:36:\"Illuminate\\Events\\CallQueuedListener\":8:{s:5:\"class\";s:42:\"App\\Listeners\\SendConfirmationNotification\";s:6:\"method\";s:6:\"handle\";s:4:\"data\";a:1:{i:0;O:21:\"App\\Events\\UserBooked\":3:{s:7:\"session\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":4:{s:5:\"class\";s:28:\"App\\Models\\FacetofaceSession\";s:2:\"id\";i:114;s:9:\"relations\";a:1:{i:0;s:10:\"facetoface\";}s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"mysql\";}s:4:\"user\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":4:{s:5:\"class\";s:8:\"App\\User\";s:2:\"id\";i:1;s:9:\"relations\";a:3:{i:0;s:26:\"facetofaceActivitySessions\";i:1;s:25:\"pendingFacetofaceSessions\";i:2;s:25:\"waitingFacetofaceSessions\";}s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"mysql\";}s:6:\"socket\";N;}}s:5:\"tries\";N;s:10:\"retryAfter\";N;s:9:\"timeoutAt\";N;s:7:\"timeout\";N;s:3:\"job\";N;}"
  }
}
```

After I use `unserialize($job_details["data"]["command"])` , I get this.;

[image]

Comment: [json_​decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) your JSON, the data in `data/command` looks serialized, so try [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: Ok, I think that  I was looking for the unserialize, but I updated the question with the output, still I am not sure how to get that ID.

Comment: My bad, it works. Thanks!

Comment: Please if you can, make the above comment as an answer. This will help others identify that your answer was the most useful/correct and solved the problem. Then, @Beusebiu can accept this answer.